# WooCommerce shortcode to ajaxify message that display: "Buy X more products to get a discount"

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

After a deep search I created a WooCommerce shortcode. The purpose of this is to display a "Buy X more products to get a discount" message.

My code:

```php
add_shortcode('check', 'custommessage');
function custommessage() {
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 6;

    if( $items_count < $min_count ){
        echo sprintf('%s products more for discount' , $min_count - $items_count );
    }
}
```

---

On WooComerce cart page, after adding X products to the cart or removing the quantity it works and refreshes automatically the message

But when I put the shortcode (on side cart) it does not auto refresh the X count. Although it is also AJAX driven.

Any advice how i can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ajaxify your message so it updates when an item is added/removed (via ajax) use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` filter hook

So you get:

```php
function custom_message() {
    // Initialize
    $message = __( 'Default message', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // True
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get number of items in the cart.
        $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        $min_count   = 6;

        if ( $items_count < $min_count ) {
            $message = sprintf( __( '%s products more for discount', 'woocommerce' ), $min_count - $items_count );
        } else {
            $message = __( 'Some message', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    
    return $message;
}

// Refreshing on cart ajax events
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {    
    $fragments['div.display-message'] = '<div class="display-message">' . custom_message() . '</div>';
    
    return $fragments;        
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 10, 1 );
```

---

**1)** Then to display this via a shortcode, use:

```php
function display_my_message() {
    return '<div class="display-message">' . custom_message() . '</div>';
} 
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode( 'display_message', 'display_my_message' );
```

> **SHORTCODE USAGE**
>
> In an existing page:
>
> `[display_message]`
>
> Or in PHP:
>
> `echo do_shortcode("[display_message]");`

**OR**

**2)** To display the message via **any desired hook** (in this example I show 2 hooks. 1 on the cart page and 1 on the single product page, adapt to your needs). Use:

```php
// Display message via the desired hooks
function display_message() {
    echo '<div class="display-message">' . custom_message() . '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'display_message', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_message', 10, 0 );
```