# Modify "get_cart_contents_count()" WooCommerce function for certain product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on [WooCommerce shortcode to ajaxify message that display: "Buy X more products to get a discount"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086176/11987538) answer code I want to add on a code to exclude a specific category from count of cart items.

According to what I found, I should use the [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) function

So here is my code attempt:

I replaced

```php
// True
if ( WC()->cart ) {
    // Get number of items in the cart.
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 6;
```

With

```php
if ( ! has_term( array('set'), 'product_cat' ) ) {
    // Get number of items in the cart.
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 6;
```

---

This does not give any error messages but also not the desired result, any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit/rewrite an existing function it is always interesting to see how the existing function is written in WooCommerce

Copied/pasted from [includes/class-wc-cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/includes/class-wc-cart.php) line 652 - 659 @version 2.1.0

```php
/**
 * Get number of items in the cart.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function get_cart_contents_count() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count', array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $this->get_cart(), 'quantity' ) ) );
}
```

As you can see it contains a filter hook, which we could use. However, in this case it is better to write our own custom function, based on the existing one

---

The function below will only count the products in cart that do NOT belong to one or more specific categories

**So you get:**

```php
// Custom function
function get_cart_contents_count_certain_categories( $the_array ) {
    // Initialize
    $count = 0;
    
    // When empty OR NOT WC()->cart
    if ( empty ( $the_array ) || ! WC()->cart ) return $count;

    // Loop trough cart items quantities
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities() as $product_id => $cart_item_quantity ) {
        // NOT has term (product category)
        if ( ! has_term( $the_array, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            // Addition
            $count += $cart_item_quantity;
        }
    }
    
    return $count;
}
```

**Optional:** to do the opposite, and count the products that DO belong to a certain category

*Replace*

```php
// NOT has term (product category)
if ( ! has_term( $the_array, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
```

*With*

```php
// Has term (product category)
if ( has_term( $the_array, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
```

---

**USAGE:**

```php
// Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
$categories = array( 'categorie-1', 65 );

// Call custom function
$items_count = get_cart_contents_count_certain_categories( $categories );

// Echo result
echo $items_count;
```

**OR**

From a certain hook

```php
// Output is placed before the products list on the shop page
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop() {
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories = array( 'categorie-1', 65 );
    
    // Call custom function and echo result
    echo get_cart_contents_count_certain_categories( $categories );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236910/discussion-between-uxell-and-7uc1f3r).

Comment: This code can be affect website performance if is active 1200 users/per second? @7uc1f3r