# WooCommerce shortcode to ajaxify message that display: "You need to spend to get free shipping"

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I modified this script to make a shortcode that shows how much the customer need to spend to get free shipping.

```php
 /** 
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.9
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_shortcode ('woo_freeshipping_target', 'woo_freeship_target' );
  
function woo_freeship_target() {
  ob_start();
    
   $min_amount = 279; //change this to your free shipping threshold
   
   $current = WC()->cart->subtotal;
  
   if ( $current < $min_amount ) {
      $added_text = wc_price( $min_amount - $current );
      $notice = sprintf( $added_text );
      echo '<span> You need to add '.$notice.'</span>';
   }
    
     else if ( $current >= $min_amount ) {
      echo '<span>Free Shipping!</span>';
   }
  
    return ob_get_clean();
    
}
```

But I cannot figure out how can I make it to auto update when the items quantity is modified. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ajaxify your message so it updates when the subtotal change (via ajax) use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` filter hook

So you get:

```php
function custom_message() {
    // Initialize
    $message = __( 'Default message', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // True
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Change this to your free shipping threshold
        $min_amount = 279;
        
        // Get cart subtotal
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

        if ( $subtotal < $min_amount ) {
            $message = sprintf( __( 'You need to add %s to get free shipping', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_amount - $subtotal ) );
        } else {
            $message = __( 'Free shipping', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    
    return $message;
}

// Refreshing on cart ajax events
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {    
    $fragments['div.display-message'] = '<div class="display-message">' . custom_message() . '</div>';
    
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 10, 1 );

// Shortcode
function display_my_message() {
    return '<div class="display-message">' . custom_message() . '</div>';
} 
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode( 'display_message', 'display_my_message' );
```

> SHORTCODE USAGE
>
> In an existing page:
>
> `[display_message]`
>
> Or in PHP:
>
> `echo do_shortcode("[display_message]");`

---

Related: [WooCommerce shortcode to ajaxify message that display: "Buy X more products to get a discount"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086176/11987538)